# When I get a font package with OTFs, should I also keep the Web versions?

Tags: fonts, redundancy, ttf

I've just downloaded the Comic Neue font family distribution zip (from [here](http://www.comicneue.com/)). It has an `OTF/` subfolder with 12 `.otf` files, and a `Web/` subfolder with 49 files - `.ttf`, `.eot`, `.woff` and `.woff2` files (same 12 base-names as the OTFs).

Is there any use for me - as a desktop user and even perhaps as a person creating raster and vector graphics, but *not* for the web / mobile world - to keep the `Web/` font files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No need to keep the web fonts.

For local use, the OTF files are sufficient. You’d only need the other files if you wanted to make them available for use in a web site; and then, you still wouldn’t need the files locally, you’d upload them to your web site.